# How to use "create_web_element" method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I got `chromedriver` version `2.9.248315` and found new method called `create_web_element(element_id)`. The only information I got from `help(driver.create_web_element)` is

> Creates a web element with the specified element_id.

Also no related information found in web.

I tried `driver.create_web_element("qwerty")` and got `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement(session="a8ca8588e6b7545c17c4d35fddac7abd", element="qwerty")>` in return

But if to try `driver.find_element_by_id('qwerty')`, `NoSuchElement` exception raised

So who can tell me what this method should actually do and how to use it correctly?

Answer (score 4):

`driver.create_web_element` only creates a `WebElement` object. It does not add this object to the DOM, therefore, it cannot be found with `find_element_by_id`.

If you want to create elements in the DOM, you can add elements  using the [relevant js functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp) and by calling `execute_script(js_code)`.

Comment: can I please ask what the purpose of this create_web_element if it can not be added to DOM?

Comment: [Searching on gihub](https://github.com/search?l=python&q=create_web_element&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) only brings implementations of this. I suspect that when writing your own webdriver this can be used to create your own custom `WebElement` instead of `selenium`'s default.